# Lights out game

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, recreational-mathematics

I would like to ask about the game Lights Out for a square nxn. In http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html there is a list of the number of solutions to the game, and the number of solutions modulo symmetries of the square. Somewhere I have seen a formula for the number of solutions for general n, written as a generating function. However I cannot locate it now. Does anyone know where it is?
And is there also a formula for the number of solutions modulo symmetries for general n?
Thanks

Comment: See also the earlier MO question, [Randomly switching street lights, in a square city](http://mathoverflow.net/a/119363/6094), concerning "Berlekamp’s Switching Game."

Answer (score 3):

http://oeis.org/A075462

The number of solutions to the all-ones lights out problem on an $n\times n$ square, where nonidentical reflected and rotated solutions are considered distinct. (The link gives the `Mathematica` code to generate the sequence.)

Similarly, http://oeis.org/A075463 gives the number of rotation-reflection inequivalent solutions.

Comment: My question is to find a closed formula (explicit formula or as a generating function) for these numbers, not just an algorithm to compute them one by one.

Comment: If there's no formula at the oeis pages, that's evidence that nobody has found one. But did you follow up on all the links at the oeis pages?